# Re-arrangable fixed(two) and fluid(one) elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout which has 3 elements, two of which have fixed width, and the third will take up the rest of the width of the parent.

[image]

**(1):** `fixed-fluid-fixed` The fluid one has 2 divs, one floated to left and another to right inside the middle fluid div.

**(2):** if I place the fixed div's next to each other, it should look like this. `fixed-fixed-fluid`.

**(3):** if one of the fixed-div is deleted, the fluid div should fill the empty space to form `fluid-fixed`

**(4):** similarly, if the later fixed-div is removed, the fluid should fill this space to become, `fixed-fluid` layout as shown.

**What I have tried:** http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/28QUr/ (problem being, I cannot rearrange the divs)

*I do not want to use js*, I am sure this can be achieved just using html-css.

Comment: You're proposing a very good challenge! I think you are looking for something like Flexbox. See these references:http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

You can set 2 or more `<div>`s like these:

```
<div id="left_column_200px">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="column_100%_of_remaining>
    <!-- content -->
</div>

#left_column_200px {
    width: 200px; height: auto; overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left; 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#column_100%_of_remaining {
    width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto; overflow; hidden; padding-left: 200px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This should work.